# Is it good practice to design UX tailored to specific audiences or just use the general UX guidelines regardless?

Tags: website-design, web, ux-designer

I work for a company where our users are generally older and less computer efficient ( based on user studies). Is it good UX practice to tailor the website experience taking that fact into account (larger fonts, more informative walkthroughs, etc). or should a UX be "good UX" universally and be focused for *all* audiences

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you are already sure about the audience then going for a trailered UX is always a better plan. Whereas if I talk about the normal/general case, I personally prefer not going for a universal idea.

Comment: +1 You should design for your audience.  However to do that you really have to know them pretty well ( and not just make assumptions based on age).  An example of this is determining the language you can use on the website: a specialist site for doctors can use language which Joe Public won't want to read.

Answer (score 0):

YES, You are referring to accessibility. It's about inclusively providing a good UX for all audiences. This includes not just older people but also people with disabilities and those with solver internet connections.

> Accessibility is the practice of making your websites usable by as
> many people as possible. We traditionally think of this as being about
> people with disabilities, but the practice of making sites accessible
> also benefits other groups such as those using mobile devices, or
> those with slow network connections. You might also think of
> accessibility as treating everyone the same, and giving them equal
> opportunities, no matter what their ability or circumstances. Just as
> it is wrong to exclude someone from a physical building because they
> are in a wheelchair (modern public buildings generally have wheelchair
> ramps or elevators), it is also not right to exclude someone from a
> website because they have a visual impairment. We are all different,
> but we are all human, and therefore have the same human rights.
> Accessibility is the right thing to do. Providing accessible sites is
> part of the law in some countries, which can open up some significant
> markets that otherwise would not be able to use your services or buy
> your products.

source
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/What_is_accessibility#:~:text=Accessibility%20is%20the%20practice%20of,those%20with%20slow%20network%20connections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/What_is_accessibility#:%7E:text=Accessibility%20is%20the%20practice%20of,those%20with%20slow%20network%20connections).

Comment: In terms of Accessibility, it is important that whatever tailoring you do the same content is available to all types of Users, because you cannot really distinguish between Users of each "group" that are or aren't blind (at least you shouldn't). Having some content only available to Golf-loving-20-20-eyesight users and not others = Accessibility failed.